# Limit as a sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

$$A = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}\dots\binom{n}{n}\right)^{1/n(n+1)}$$

We need to find the value of $A$.

---

**My attempt:** I tried taking log both the sides and went from there.

$$ \ln A = \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(\frac1{n(n+1)} \bigg[(n+1) \ln n! - 2 \sum_{k=0}^n(n-k+1) \ln k )\bigg]\bigg)$$

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Also, can we some how utilize gamma function in this question since we will be dealing with factorials?

Comment: I think the answer is $\sqrt{e}$, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: See also [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1574818p9688695) and [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1348679p7353456).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks